# How can I change multiple properties on the same and different nodes at the same time?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, properties, blur

I'm working in the compositor, and I have several blur nodes that look like the following:

[image]

I want to make it so that I can control both the x and the y values at the same time. I also want to make it so that I can control the x and y on another Blur node as well. So in the end, I would only need to change 1 value, and both the x and y on the 2 (or more) blur nodes would all change as well, to the same value.

The first thing I thought of doing was creating a sort of "macro" controller, something like a slider that I could connect to each node to control the x and y properties. I couldn't find anything on that either beyond just using a mapping node, which seems a little overkill... so any help would be appreciated there as well.

After looking into that though, I realized that the X and Y properties don't even have a socket... so that's where I'm stuck. Is it possible to "reveal" the socket for the X and Y nodes? They seem to be integers which is one of the available socket types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The X/Y dimensions of the Blur node are properties, not inputs, so they can’t be controlled via a socket. However, if you just want a convenient way to control them all together, you can use *drivers*, instead:

[image]